# How to fix appended list having output greater than input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, opencv, enumeration

**Summarize the Problem**
I am running a list of images through a CNN model using OpenCV and face_recognition modules. I have ran the entry multiple times but continue ending with a list greater than the input.

**Background on what has been tried**

a. Encode the images first, then run a secondary process whereby each encoded entry is ran against itself (i+1), utilizing `face_recognition.compare_faces`.

b. Encoding the images then loading the encoded pickle file and enumerating through each image from the original file extraction location.

Note on data:
-`imagePaths` is a list of **293** .png files.

-`encodings.pickle` is a dictionary of those images in `imagePaths` that have already been encoded.

**Show some code**

The source code has been modified from that shown [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/18/face-recognition-with-opencv-python-and-deep-learning/).

```py
data = pickle.loads(open("encodings.pickle","rb").read())

imagePaths = list(paths.list_images("./images")

matchesOutput = []

for (i,imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
  d = dt.datetime.now()
  print(d.isoformat())
  print("[INFO] processing image {}/{}".format(i + 1, 
        len(imagePaths)))
  image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
  rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,model = 'cnn')
  encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb,boxes)
  names = []

  for encoding in encodings:
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],encoding)
    name = "Unknown"

    if True in matches:
        matchedIdx=[i for (i,b) in enumerate (matches) if b]
        matchesOutput.append(matchedIdxs)
```

**Describe expected | actual results:**

*Expected*:
A list (`matchesOutput`) of length `293`. Where each index is equal to `matchedIdxs` for *.*

*Actual*:
A list (`matchesOutput`) of length **330**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going through each image path (293 entries) and then for each of those looking at all encodings (presumably also 293 entries) and if there are any matches for that encoding, appending the matched indexes. Therefore for each image path, depending on how accurate the `face_recognition.compare_faces` method is, you may get more than one matching encoding or none (which should only happen if the method is very weak, since each image is also in the encoded list), and hence more (or potentially less) than 293 values in your final list.

Even with a very accurate predictor the images might contain identical twins for example or two images of the same person, and so 330 which is the number of matches you are seeing, might even be the correct output.

If you want a list of exactly 293, you will have to decide on how to choose between multiple matches (i.e. what is the best match) and potentially what to append if no matches occur.

Comment: interesting. I noted on the ouput that there were duplicates and I was wondering if it was a 'hiccup' as it was quite slow (since I have yet to get CUDA to work and thus CPU used). Interesting...have you encountered this before? I wonder if I should just delete dups...

Comment: I haven't done much work in image recognition, but deciding on how to deal with false positives is a classic part of classification problems. I guess it depends on what your goal is and what you need the final list for. In general the usual approach is to choose the "best" match or if your data is very large, the first match that is better than some threshold that you decide beforehand.